# JS message 'is not a function' in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is the following code:

```
class OrdersBySalonUpdater

    sendRequestToUpdateOrders: ->
        console.log('123')
        startDate = transformDate($("#from_datepicker"))
        endDate     = transformDate($("#to_datepicker"))
        businessId = $(".maininfo__datepickerwrap").attr("data-business-id")

        url = "some url"

        $.get url, (data) ->
            @updateOrders(data.orders)

    updateOrders: (orders) ->
        $("#salon_stat_table tr").slice(1).remove()
        $.each orders, (index) ->
            console.log(orders[index])
```

But when I execute the following:

```
    x = new OrdersBySalonUpdater()
    x.sendRequestToUpdateOrders()
```

I got the message "TypeError: this.updateOrders is not a function". How can I fix it? What's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `this` is a context object. It can change, often when we don't want it to.

When you write `@updateOrders(data.orders)`, CoffeeScript converts that to the JavaScript `this.updateOrders(data.orders)`. However, you're calling `updateOrders` within a callback from jQuery's `$.get`. When your code gets executed, `this` no longer refers to your `OrdersBySalonUpdater` class - it's [the context passed in the Ajax settings, or the settings themselves](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

---

There's three ways we could solve this. The last is best - it's shortest, and the most idiomatic CoffeeScript.

1. **Store the current value of `this`, and use it within your callback**. `this` can change, but if we store its current value in a variable then we can use it later. It's a common convention to call those variables `that`:

   ```
   sendRequestToUpdateOrders: ->
     that = this
     url = "some url"

     $.get url, (data) ->
       that.updateOrders(data.orders)
   ```
2. **Pass `this` into your callback as the context**. jQuery lets us pass a `context` option to our Ajax methods. Whatever we pass will be available within the callback as `this`:

   ```
   sendRequestToUpdateOrders: ->
     url = "some url"

     $.get url, 
       success: (data) ->
         @updateOrders(data.orders)
       context: this
   ```
3. **Use the CoffeeScript fat-arrow to write your callback**. The fat arrow [defines a function and binds `this` for you](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

   ```
   sendRequestToUpdateOrders: ->
     url = "some url"

     $.get url, (data) =>
       @updateOrders(data.orders)
   ```